# Audio on all videos is pitch shifted way down, no matter the source

Tags: sound

Recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on Acer Revo-One-RL85. Audio sounds like it's in extreme slow motion, but is actually the same speed as normal, it's just pitch-shifted down a couple of octaves. Really weird, and I can't find any guidance.

Comment: Yes, doesn't matter the source of the video.  I just deleted and reinstalled pavucontrol using instructions found on this site, but the problem remains...

Comment: Reloaded pulseaudio, and the problem remains.

Comment: Installed VLC media player; problem remains.